# cannot use the current-datetime function in xslt

Tags: c#, xslt

I am not able to use the current-dateTime function in xslt. this is what my stylesheet declaration looks like.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
```

Every time I compile I get an error that current-dateTime is not a XSLT function

And this is how I am calling the function.

```
<xsl:variable name="currentTime" select="current-dateTime()" />
```

Comment: Well do you use an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 or XQSharp or AltovaXML Tools? There are lots of XSLT 1.0 processors that have not been updated to support XSLT 2.0.

Comment: no i am not using any those processor.. i am just tranforming my xslt using .net 3.5

Comment: If you use .NET 3.5 and want to use XSLT 2.0 then you have the choice between the XSLT 2.0 processors I mentioned. The built-in `System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform` does not support XSLT 2.0, it is an XSLT 1.0 processor.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned above, .net framework does not support XSLT 2.0. One solution for executing custom functions is to use [Xslt Extension Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tf741884.aspx)