# Get current day in week with xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

How can i get the current day of week in xslt. Like Monday, tuesday.... 
0,1,2 would also be acceptable.

How can I do this in XSLT?

Comment: Possible duplicate except the date format - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9394322/xslt-1-0-get-current-datetime

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since it's XSLT 2.0:

```
 format-date(current-date(), '[F]')
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at link,this may help you http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx_day-of-week.html